# What is diffrence between OriginalPathInfo() and PathInfo()

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, url, core

In `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Varien_Router_Standard::checkShouldBeSecure` there is object `$request`
What is difference between `getOriginalPathInfo()` and `getPathInfo()` methods of `$request`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getOriginalPathInfo` will always return the URI that you called.
`getPathInfo` will return what is being processed internally by Magento, after looking through the url rewrites table

Let's take this example.

http://something.com/electronics.html.  - this is the category page for the category with id 13 (I used the sample data).

`getOriginalPathInfo` will return `/electronics.html`
`getPathInfo` will return `catalog/category/view/id/13`

If there is no value in the url rewrites table for the url you request then both methods return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you are looking for:

> ## File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

```
// get controller name
if ($request->getControllerName()) {
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
} else {
    if (!empty($p[1])) {
        $controller = $p[1];
    } else {
        $controller = $front->getDefault('controller');
        $request->setAlias(
            Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            ltrim($request->getOriginalPathInfo(), '/')
        );
    }
}
```

In the code above, We first ask the request object if a custom controller has been set elsewhere. If not (the normal state of affairs first time through), we look at the second part of our path information ($p[1]). If there’s nothing in there, we go to the default set on the front controller object (in a normal operating system, that’s index)

```
$pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
```

This is the code that pulls the path information from the request object.